# Why does holds_alternative build without std namespace

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Why does holds_alternative build without std namespace?
I have tested this with godbolt.org using different compiles and it builds.

```
#include <variant>
int main()
{
    std::variant<int, double> foo = 1;
    bool wuff = holds_alternative<int>(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Tested example with https://godbolt.org/z/1YoMq1seY with different compilers

Comment: The search term is "Argument Dependent Lookup".

Comment: ADL with explicit specification of template parameter(s) works only since C++20.